# Elementwise addition of lists in F#

Tags: list, f#, addition

I'm trying to figure out how to do elementwise multiplication of two lists in F#. Example: [1;2;3]+[1;2;3;4]=[2;4;6;4]. I'm quite a newbie and still struggle with the syntax of the code. My try is as follows:

```
let plus list_1 list_2 = function
    | list_1 list_2 -> [| for xi in list_1 yield
                          list_1[i]+list_2[i]
                          |];;
```

It just give me an error, but can't figure out how to change it so it becomes right.

As a side note, if somebody know a beginner place to learn about lists in F#, a point in the right direction, is appreciated :)

Comment: If you are interested in this because of math, then be aware that there are far better ways to handle matrices and operations on them in .NET and F#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had two lists of the same size, then the easiest solution would be to use the `List.map2` function. This takes two lists and it applies a specified function pairwise - so if you pass it `(+)` as a function, it does exactly what you want:

```
let l1 = [1;2;3]
let l2 = [3;2;1]

List.map2 (+) l1 l2
```

If your lists are of different size, then this is going to crash. I do not think there is any simple built-in solution, but you could define a function `pad` to pad a list with zeros and then make sure both lists are of the same size:

```
let pad n l = 
  List.append l 
    (List.init (n-List.length l) (fun _ -> 0))

let l1 = [1;2;3]
let l2 = [3;2;1;4]
let l = max (List.length l1) (List.length l2)

List.map2 (+) (pad l l1) (pad l l2)
```

Answer (score 1):

In a similar vein to Tomas's answer, this makes both lists the "same" (infinite) length (using the lazy `Seq` instead of eager `List`), then trims the result to just the maximum length of the two lists:

```
let l1 = [1;2;3]
let l2 = [3;2;1;4]

let zeroes = Seq.initInfinite (fun _ -> 0)

let result =
    Seq.map2 (+) (Seq.append l1 zeroes) (Seq.append l2 zeroes)
    |> Seq.take (max (List.length l1) (List.length l2))
    |> Seq.toList
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two different solutions. Both combine the elements, that can be combined, and concatenate the result, onto the end.

It's up to you, to understand, how they work.

```ml
(* Avoiding SO syntax highlighting issues *)
let add x y = x + y
let mul x y = x * y


let dol f xs ys =
    let minElements = min (List.length xs) (List.length ys)
    List.append
        (List.map2 f (List.take minElements xs) (List.take minElements ys))        
        (List.skip minElements (if List.length xs = minElements then ys else xs))
 
dol add [1;2;3] [2;3;4;5;6] (* [3; 5; 7; 5; 6]  *)
dol mul [1;2;3] [2;3;4;5;6] (* [2; 6; 12; 5; 6] *)


let rec mol f xs ys =
    match xs,ys with
    | [],[]       -> []
    | [],ys       -> ys
    | xs,[]       -> xs
    | x::xs,y::ys -> (f x y) :: (mol f xs ys)

mol add [1;2;3] [2;3;4;5;6] (* [3; 5; 7; 5; 6]  *)
mol mul [1;2;3] [2;3;4;5;6] (* [2; 6; 12; 5; 6] *)
```